# How to extract video from only one part of a multi rar package without downloading the rest

Tags: extract, rar

I want to see only one video from a package of 10. All of these are in a multi part rar package. Does it mean that I need to download all 10 for the extraction to work properly or is there a way around downloading only what I need. Also for eg. I need to see only part 5, could it work if I download part 4, 5 and 6 and then try to extract ?

thanks

Comment: Please clarify. Are there ten video files split across multiple RAR files?

Comment: You have to download the whole thing to extract any part of it.  It has to do with how compression works -- no one segment is an independent part.

Comment: Here's an article that explains a bit about lossless data compression, in relatively basic terms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this by creating a split solid RAR archive, then deleting all parts except two from the middle. Some files spanned more than these parts, whereas others were contained in just these two. I was successfully able to extract the latter files.

So basically if you download just the parts that you know for sure contain the complete video, you should have no problems extracting it.

Note that if you see `Filename -->` in one of the parts it means that file is continued in the next part of the archive. If you attempt to extract it without having the subsequent archive part RAR will complain with "**You need to have the following volume to continue extraction: `<volume name>`**".

If on the other hand you see `Filename <--` in one of the parts it means that file is continued from a previous part of the archive. If you attempt to extract it without having the previous  archive part RAR will complain with "**You need to start extraction from a previous volume to unpack `<filename>`**".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the video is right in the middle, you would need to download the first part, and then all parts up to that point. Be careful though, as some algorithms and archives will also fragment as files are added or removed, which may mean you need every part of the archive. Sorry, but it will depend.

The first part of the archive includes the index, so that will always be needed. That tells the archive utility where the files are, at which marker, in which file.